# How to view Snort logs in ELK (Windows)?

Tags: windows, elk, snort

how to view logs from Snort in ELK? The unified2 format is not supported by Logstash.

One way would be to setup a Linux VM  that runs Barnyard2 to convert and send it to ELK SIEM. I wonder if there is an easier option inside the Windows machine producing the logs while running Snort.

Thanks

Nothing tested yet. Trying to finger out best solution.